# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in Select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is the table
**City**

```
Def
Abc
Ijkl
Mnop
```

And
I want the output, where the smallest city name is returned, who have same number of characters.
OUTPUT

```
Abc 3
Ijkl 4
```

Notice that there were 2 cities with same number of characters Abc and Def, and only Abc will be returned.

The Oracle SQL query which i am trying to run is -

```
Select a.city,a.leng from
(
Select city,length(city) as leng from station 
order by 2,1
) as a where a.leng in (
Select distinct(length(city)) from station 
order by 1);
```

I hope there will be numerous ways to solve but i want to correct my approach.

Comment: Also to add, both the subquery work fine, if I run them separately, but i am unable to combine them

Answer (score 1):

A simple group by should give you the desired result

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    station (city)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Def' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Abc' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Ijkl' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Mnop' FROM DUAL)
  SELECT MIN (city) as city, LENGTH (city) as leng
    FROM station
GROUP BY LENGTH (city)
order by leng;
```

#### Result

```
   CITY    LENG
_______ _______
Abc           3
Ijkl          4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to over complicate this with subqueries.
This should give you the desired result

```
Select MIN(City), LENGTH(City)
From station
Group By LENGTH(City)
```